# What's the equivalent of func_get_args for variables passed with use?

Tags: php

I was wondering if there was a way to list variables were exposed to a closure using `use`, like what `func_get_args()` does with normal parameters.

#### [Example](https://3v4l.org/3saRL)

```
<?php

$hello = 'Hello';
$arr = ['Foo'];

array_walk($arr, function($item) use($hello) {
    echo "$hello $item \n\n";
    print_r(func_get_args());
    // Here, is there a way to list variables passed with `use`?
});
```

Comment: Use isn't really passing the parameters in, it's allowing your global variables to be used inside your function. I don't believe there is a way to get a list.

Comment: Why would you need this? You can't do the `use()` list dynamically, like arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this slightly modified version of your code:

```
<?php

$hello = 'Hello';
$arr = ['Foo'];
$invisible = 'hopefully';

array_walk($arr, function($item) use($hello) {
    echo "$hello $item \n\n";
    print_r(func_get_args());
    print_r(get_defined_vars());
});
```

The output of this is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Foo
    [1] => 0
)
Array
(
    [item] => Foo
    [hello] => Hello
)
```

That probably answers your question, the intersection of the two should be the list of variables in the `use()` construct...

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring that it makes no sense to fetch the variables passed in the `use` statement. Because they can't change during execution.

But it is possible from outside through PHP's reflection API:

```
<?php
$a = 42;

$b = function () use ($a) {
    echo $a;
};

$refl = new ReflectionFunction($b);
var_dump($refl->getStaticVariables());
```

Output:

```
$ php test.php
array(1) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(42)
}
```